# What is meant by 'bumped to the homepage'?

Tags: support, bump

I saw this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80545/87130) on main site. This question has **bumped to the homepage** by *[Community](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)*. Description is given as *This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.*, that I understand.

My question is what is mean by "bumped to the homepage"? What is the homepage referring here? When do we do this and who can do this?

Now when I am looking at the above *question* there is no *'bumped to the homepage'* mark. How did it get removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every hour, the Community user finds a question with at least one answer, but none of the answers have a score greater than 0, and there's been no activity for 30 days or more. To gain exposure, it "bumps" them to the homepage, i.e., [the main page of Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), by making a silent edit. (Why it's called "bumping", I don't know. I prefer the similar "nudging", but "bumping" is what gained a foothold in most discussion forums and related sites.)

This activity isn't new; this has been happening for a long time. They've only recently added the text to let you know it's been "bumped". This distinguishes it from other actions which kind of look the same, like a spam answer being auto-deleted. I expect this is to encourage the reader to give the answers a good review and vote accordingly.

As for why the message isn't there any more, I'm sure it's because someone edited a post (either the question or an answer), so that's the reason that the question is appearing high in the list of questions on the home page. ([The "bump" message ages away after three days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287445/bumped-to-the-homepage-by-community-after-suggested-edit-approved-by-community?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment933673_287467), but it doesn't look that that's what happened here.)

See also: [How can we make the purpose of Community "bumping" more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279203)

Comment: Aha!.. good to know all these things. :)